# Oracle view: How to display only days in future?

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I need to display in oracle view only future values from data column, so my script looks like this:

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "CH"."BK_VIEW_SCHEDULE" AS SELECT (CASE when dt_date>=SYSDATE-1 THEN dt_date end) AS dat from bk_date`

Table with source dates:

[image]

But it returns past dates as null

[image]

How can i achieve only future date values without past date null rows?

I know that this select query works as i need:

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "CH"."BK_VIEW_SCHEDULE" AS  SELECT  (SELECT dt_date FROM bk_date WHERE dt_date>=SYSDATE-1) AS dat from bk_date ORDER BY dt_date;`,

but in views it throws error *ORA-01427: Subquery returns more than one row*.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Something is missing from your question, because your question has no subqueries, but you claim to be getting that as an error message.

Comment: added full query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it returns past dates as null

A case expression with no filter will still return all rows in the base table; you have no `else` clause in the case expression so when the condition is not matched you get the default null.

Your second attempt:

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "CH"."BK_VIEW_SCHEDULE" AS
> SELECT  (SELECT dt_date FROM bk_date WHERE dt_date>=SYSDATE-1) AS dat from bk_date
> ORDER BY dt_date
> ```

... has an unnecessary subquery. That returns all the future rows, which causes the ORA-01427 error - unless the base table only contains a single future date.

You can just use the filter you already know works, with no subquery needed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW BK_VIEW_SCHEDULE AS
SELECT dt_date FROM bk_date WHERE dt_date>=SYSDATE-1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d39b794707c27dd1ea406c020b8eec13)

It doesn't make sense to have an `order by` clause in the view definition. It's allowed, syntactically; but there is no guarantee that a query against the view will return the data in that order, unless that query has its own `order by` clause - which makes the one in the view definition redundant.

Comment: thanks, but if i need to add some more columns in view, like that :

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW BK_VIEW_SCHEDULE AS 
  SELECT dt_date FROM bk_date WHERE dt_date>=SYSDATE-1,
  rm_name AS room
  from bk_date, bk_room;`

it throws ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Well, yes, because you have the `where` clause in the wrong place? How are the two tables related?

Comment: well, thanks my dumb head finally realised, that i just needed to move 'where' part to the end of script